# How to add unique menu for a page?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to add a mega menu for my page in word press, but its should be unique menu. And its should not my page menu(primary menu). and the mega menu should be call by using short code.

Comment: what have you tried so far...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Mega menu I have tried. its working fine, in case any thing for future will ask you.

Comment: Is there any way to list my custom page names in left side of the page? using plugin/widget? 
only the mapped page should display in the left side of the page is there any plugin/widget? can you suggest.

Comment: can you use custom css, javascript ?